# Is it possible to source a file in a shell without using `. ` (dot space)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file `bashrc` that creates a bunch of variables and references to programs that I don't usually want to have in my bash shell, so it's not part of my `~/.bashrc` file, and if I need them I can just source it source `~/path/bashrc`.

To not have to type the whole path because I use it with some frequency, I have a script in one of the directories in my `$PATH` that contains just a couple of lines to source it

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/path/bashrc
```

suppose the script if called `extra-stuff`. I know that to run it without sourcing the file to a subshell I have to run it with a dot in front

```
. extra-stuff
```

Is there a way to have this happen without having to use the `.` ? So is there a way to source some extra part of what would normally be .bashrc by calling a script as you would call any other random binary file?

Comment: What for? Why use something else then `.`?

Comment: `.` (dot) is an alias for source. See `man source`

Comment: Put an alias in your `.profile` : `alias src_bashrc='source ~/path/bashrc'`. then you can just call it .

Comment: @MyUserIsThis : If you are reluctant to dirty the dot-key on your keyboard, you can also run it with `source extra-stuff`. Another alternative is to use an alias (as LMC suggested), or, for more flexibility, a shell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to source some extra part of what would normally be .bashrc by calling a script as you would call any other random binary file?

Not by calling a script. But you can call a function instead. In your `~/.bashrc` write

```
extrastuff() {
  source path/to/optional/rc/file
}
```

or even leaven out the optional rc file by directly writing everything into the function:

```
extrastuff() {
  # do stuff just as you would do in path/to/optional/rc/file
  # only if you use declare/typeset, you have to add the -g option
}
```

Then, inside your interactive terminal session, type `extrastuff` to execute that function.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly running a binary but exactly the kind of behaviour I expected